# Finding the maximum of an array without using explicit conditionals

Tags: java

Some people complain about `if` - statements and I really appreciate that attitude. Actually I plan to abandon the entire keyword in order to awesomize my code, which is:

**Algorithm.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.noxx;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This is algorithm. It works as .. there is no need for .. - statements.
 * It proves that there is no need for .. - statements.
 */
public class Algorithm {

    /**
     * ..less algorithm for finding the index of a maximum integer in an array.
     * 
     * @param  array the array to search.
     * @return the index of the maximum element or -1 if the array is
     *         <code>null</code> or has length zero.
     */
    public static final int indexOfMaximum(final int[] array) {
        int max;
        int index;

        // Here supposed check whether array is null or empty, but we are not
        // supposed to use ..-statements. Use exceptions instead!
        try {
            max = array[0];
            index = 0;
        } catch (final NullPointerException | 
                       ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
            // Why not to use for's test condition instead of ..?
            for (int j = 0; j < testIsGreater(array[i], max); ++j) {
                max = array[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Life is so much easier now without .. .
     */
    private static int testIsGreater(final int element, final int max) {
        return element - max;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Random rnd = new Random();
        final int[] array = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i] = rnd.nextInt(1301) - 300;
        }

        final int index = indexOfMaximum(array);
        final int check = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();

        System.out.println("Maximum integer: " + array[index] 
                                               + " and " 
                                               + check);
    }
}
```

**AlgorithmTest.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.noxx;

import static net.coderodde.noxx.Algorithm.indexOfMaximum;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class AlgorithmTest {

    /**
     * My tests use .. neither! Ain't this keeewl??
     */
    @Test
    public void testIndexOfMaximum() {
        int[] array = new int[0];
        assertEquals(-1, indexOfMaximum(array));
        assertEquals(-1, indexOfMaximum(null));

        array = new int[]{3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1 };

        assertEquals(4, indexOfMaximum(array));

        array = new int[]{3};

        assertEquals(0, indexOfMaximum(array));

        array = new int[]{3, 4, 1, 7};

        assertEquals(3, indexOfMaximum(array));
    }    
}
```

So is it kewl to awesomize the code this way?

Comment: Is this a riddle?  Are you like a "Knight Who Says Ni" and can't say a certain two letter word?

Comment: For those who don't get it: `..` = `if`

Comment: This is cute but it's extremely unclear what the heck you wanted. I thought you mean `...` operator.

Comment: Note also that `element - max` can overflow (use `Integer.compare`).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Thanks...i was about to wonder WTF `..` means in Java.

Comment: Though now i'm wondering what'll happen when OP realizes that every `for`, `while`, or `?:` expression has an `if` hidden in it.  :)

Comment: @cHao the [`for` tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) didn't say anything about that. *\*cough\*sarcasm\*cough\**

Comment: I can understand why you wanted to edit your question, but please don't edit the code in question. I have rolled back your last edit. Also, I had voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking" prior to noticing the edit history. I can't change my reasoning officially, so I'll let you know here that I think this should be closed because you're not seriously seeking a Code Review. In other words, I don't believe that you really "want this to be good code".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this violates the on-topic scope questions: *Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)* - this is clearly a desire to do something "similar" and is not looking to create good code.

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes? It's obvious that it's not production code to be used in a real application; it might be for a programming challenge, an experiment, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(*please dial your sarcasm meter to `Long.MAX_VALUE`... it's a slow weekend*)

### Bug

```
 * @return the index of the maximum element or -1 if the array is
 *         <code>null</code> or has length zero.
```

Your Javadoc is using the `..` keyword, didn't your custom compiler throw an error for that? Mine did!

### `Algorithm` class name

`Algorithm` is too generic and does not communicate the awesomeness that you are trying to do here. I have a suggestion below, do consider!

### Multiple `try-catch` is not awesome enough

Ok, so you know a nifty feature, but it's not awesome enough to just catch two of them. Why not just catch on all `Throwable`s? The more things to catch, the more awesome!

### Nested `for` loops is confusing

Your nested `for` loops uses `i` and `j` variables, which may look confusing for the myopic programmer without glasses on. Why not use something, like... [recursion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90242/27975)? Yes, recursion!

### `OOP`

There is hardly any other classes in use, how else will you be able to demonstrate that you have a [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) idea about [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)? You should consider using basic classes like those from the Collections framework or primitive wrappers to do so!

### Putting all the awesomeness together

```
public class WithoutTheKeywordWhichMustNotBeNamed {

    // we need to start from one less than 0
    private static final int START_INDEX = -1;

    public static final int indexOfMaximum(int[] array) {
        // this is a container
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(START_INDEX,
                Integer.MIN_VALUE));
        try {
            recurseAwesomely(array, START_INDEX, result);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        } finally {
            return result.get(0); // awesome
        }
    }

    private static Entry<Integer, Integer> recurseAwesomely(int[] array, int index,
            List<Integer> result) {
        for (; array[++index] > result.get(1); result.addAll(Arrays.asList(index,
                array[index]))) {
            result.clear();
        }
        return recurseAwesomely(array, index, result);
    }
}
```

The idea is to recurse continuously until we get a `Throwable` due to overflowing awesomeness. We use a `List` out of convenience to store our results across recursions ('container'). We also use our `for` loop in an unconventional yet awesome way, by *incrementing during* the comparison, and *saving the results* as the increment statement (which is run after the body is done). Therefore, when our condition is `true`, we only need to clear our `results` for saving. `finally`, we have our last index saved, so we can `return` to the caller from the `result` container. Last but not least, remember to leave an awesome comment for our `private static final` variable!

Overall, I think this is an awesome question, hence I am rewarding it in the direction of awesomeness it deserves!

(*please reset your sarcasm meter back to whatever it was originally*)

---

### On a serious note

Please don't use exceptions to replace `..`, for a variety of reasons:

- `..` is simpler to write
- `..` is simpler to understand
- `..` treats a `false` condition normally as well, instead of making the JVM jump through error stacktraces
- Generally, it's just horrible code smell

The lesson here is: Don't replace `..` with exceptions. [@janos's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90197/27975) has already hit the nail on its head.

Answer (score 15):

> Some people complain about .. - statements and I really appreciate that attitude. Actually I plan to abandon the entire keyword in order to awesomize my code

I'm wondering what complaints you're referring to.
In any case, I don't think you succeeded in awesomizing,
but rather in suckifying.

---

> ```
> // Here supposed check whether array is null or empty, but we are not
> // supposed to use ..-statements. Use exceptions instead!
> try {
>     max = array[0];
>     index = 0;
> } catch (final NullPointerException | 
>                ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
>     return -1;
> }
> ```

The statement in the comment is plain wrong.
You *are* supposed to use `if` statement to check for nulls and array bounds.
(Recommended reading: Item 57 in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.)

Exceptional logic shouldn't be used for normal program flow.
What you're doing here is essentially input validation,
which fits well within the bounds of normal program flow.
Just use an `if` statement.

---

> ```
> // Why not to use for's test condition instead of ..?
> for (int j = 0; j < testIsGreater(array[i], max); ++j) {
>     max = array[i];
>     index = i;
> }
> ```

Because this is horrible code,
obfuscating an otherwise simple logic,
and looping unnecessarily.

---

> ```
> /**
>  * Life is so much easier now without .. .
>  */
> private static int testIsGreater(final int element, final int max) {
>     return element - max;
> }
> ```

Is life really easier? Harder to read, with no benefits whatsoever, so no it isn't.

Also a poor name for a function. `isGreater` would have been better.

---

Related discussions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain